# SQL Server 2008 R2 Reporting Services - Get Subscription + Schedule Link

Tags: c#, .net, reporting-services, sql-server-2008-r2

Using SQL Server 2008 R2, .NET 4, and C#, I'm having some trouble finding out how I can link a report schedule, and report subscriptions.

I can get a list of all the reports, of all the subscriptions, and of all the schedules, that's fine and working. So I have my data in its rawest form, but when trying to find some way to get a list of all subscriptions that use ScheduleA, for example, I simply cannot find anything.

I've searched MSDN, spent the afternoon trawling Google, all to no avail. I'm hoping that it's not as difficult as it seems, because it really shouldn't be.

Comment: It seems that you need to call GetSubscriptionProperties() for every subscription. MatchData out parameter will be either serialized schedule definition, or GUID of a shared schedule. Pass that GUID to GetScheduleProperties

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the person who commented on my original question, that led me to having a method which accepted a schedule ID, and doing the following once I'd got the reports:

```
var subscriptions = service.ListSubscriptions(report.Path);

foreach (var subscription in subscriptions)
{
    ExtensionSettings settings;
    string description, status, eventType, matchData;
    ActiveState state;
    ParameterValue[] parameters;
    string user = service.GetSubscriptionProperties(subscription.SubscriptionID, out settings,
                                                    out description, out state, out status, out eventType,
                                                    out matchData, out parameters);
    if (matchData == scheduleId)
    {
        // Do what I need to do
    }
}
```

This ended up giving me the solution I was looking for. Now I'm on to a different problem, unfortunately, but I'll make a different question for that if I need to.